# Optimizing pig script

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I am trying to generate aggregated output. The issue is that all the data is going to a single reducer(Filter and Count are creating a problem). How can I optimize the following script?

Expected output:
group, 10,2,12,34...

```
data = LOAD '/input/useragents' USING PigStorage('\t') AS (Col1:chararray,Col2:chararray,Col3:chararray,col4:chararray,col5:chararray);

grp1 = GROUP data BY  UA PARALLEL 50;
fr1 = FOREACH grp1 {
        fltrCol1 = FILTER data BY Col1 == 'Other';
        fltrCol2 = FILTER data BY Col2 == 'Other';
        fltrCol3 = FILTER data BY Col3 == 'Other';
        fltrCol4 = FILTER data BY col4 == 'Other';
        fltrCol5 = FILTER data BY col5 == 'Other';
        cnt_fltrCol1 = COUNT(fltrCol1);
        cnt_fltrCol2 = COUNT(fltrCol2);
        cnt_fltrCol3 = COUNT(fltrCol3);
        cnt_fltrCol4 = COUNT(fltrCol4);
        cnt_fltrCol5 = COUNT(fltrCol5);
        GENERATE group,cnt_fltrCol1,cnt_fltrCol2,cnt_fltrCol3,cnt_fltrCol4,cnt_fltrCol5;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could put the filter logic before the group by adding fltrCol{1,2,3,4,5} columns as integers, than sum them up. From the top of my head here is the script :

```
    data = LOAD '/input/useragents' USING PigStorage('\t') AS (Col1:chararray,Col2:chararray,Col3:chararray,col4:chararray,col5:chararray);

    filter = FOREACH data GENERATE UA, 
        ((Col1 == 'Other') ? 1 : 0) as fltrCol1, 
        ((Col2 == 'Other') ? 1 : 0) as fltrCol2, 
        ((Col3 == 'Other') ? 1 : 0) as fltrCol3, 
        ((Col4 == 'Other') ? 1 : 0) as fltrCol4, 
        ((Col5 == 'Other') ? 1 : 0) as fltrCol5; 

    grp1 = GROUP data BY UA PARALLEL 50;

    fr1 = FOREACH grp1 {
            cnt_fltrCol1 = SUM(fltrCol1);
            cnt_fltrCol2 = SUM(fltrCol2);
            cnt_fltrCol3 = SUM(fltrCol3);
            cnt_fltrCol4 = SUM(fltrCol4);
            cnt_fltrCol5 = SUM(fltrCol5);
            GENERATE group,cnt_fltrCol1,cnt_fltrCol2,cnt_fltrCol3,cnt_fltrCol4,cnt_fltrCol5;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Alex. There was some data issue and now it is working fine. I will implement your idea for optimization.